# DialogBox in Revit

Tags: c#, dialog, revit

I would like to ask if someone can provide guidance or some link to information related creaiton of dialog box in revit, using C#.

Basically, I want to create a dialog box that appears on screen when user push the button on revit ribbon. In dialog box he must be able to enter information and than this information to be used for analysis.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window along with its code and logic as a custom dialog box.  See the "custom dialog" section here: [Custom Dialog Boxes (wpf)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview#custom-dialog-boxes) or here for windows forms: [Dialog Boxes in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/dialog-boxes-in-windows-forms).  The dialog box can be displayed when the user presses a ribbon button.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote a series of posts on how to write external commands in Revit:

1. http://archi-lab.net/revit-beyond-macros-building-your-tools-as-external-commands/
2. http://archi-lab.net/building-revit-plug-ins-with-visual-studio-part-one/
3. http://archi-lab.net/building-revit-plug-ins-with-visual-studio-part-two/
4. http://archi-lab.net/building-revit-plug-ins-with-visual-studio-part-three/
5. http://archi-lab.net/create-your-own-tab-and-buttons-in-revit/

In general I would suggest looking at their official documentation and examples from the SDK: https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/revit

They got some decent videos there.